# Nginx string manipulation on a variable

Tags: regex, string, nginx, reverse-proxy

Is there a way i can apply string replace on a nginx variable. I am using nginx as a proxy for s3 restricted downloads. And i am forwarding the `$upstream_http_etag` to the response header with the different name.

```
add_header Content-MD5 $upstream_http_etag;
proxy_set_header Content-MD5 $upstream_http_etag;
```

The problem is etag is `double quoted`. I wanted to remove this double quotes before adding it to the header. Is there a possible way to do this.

I know i can strip it down on the client. But this is for older apps to work without the updates.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is use [header_filter_by_lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#header_filter_by_lua) directive of lua-nginx-module instead of add_header directive.

For example,

```
location / {
    header_filter_by_lua '
            -- delete double quoted
            local value = string.gsub(ngx.var.upstream_http_etag or "", [[^"(.+)"$]], "%1")
            -- add response header
            ngx.header["Content-MD5"] = value
    ';
    proxy_pass ...;
}
```

BTW, `proxy_set_header` is used to pass extra request header to upstream,
however, `$upstream_http_etag` is upstream response header.
So `proxy_set_header Content-MD5 $upstream_http_etag;` makes no sense.